# :list-messages is not showing exact expected result

Tags: jboss7.x, hornetq

I am using JBoss 7.1.1 version. I can see from message count from CLI.

**:count-messages**

```
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => 177L
}
```

**:list-messages**

```
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => []
}
```

Why does `:count-messages` indicate there are 177 messages but `:list-messages` contains an empty list?

Answer (score 0):

Some old versions of hornetq used to only show in memory messages, ignoring paged messages, which was fixed on a later release.

verify if you don't have paged messages on your system. Try upgrading to artemis or a newer version of hornetq

Comment: ThanQ Clebert for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Do you confirm it? if so, please accept the answer.. otherwise let me know and I will look for you.

Comment: I am currently using hornetQ server version 2.2.13.Final which is embedded with version jboss 7.1.1 Final. Do you have any idea exactly in which version of hornetq this got resolved/ better version ?.